# echo string variable in html p tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo a random string variable but i am formatting my echo statement incorrectly.

```
$strings = array('string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3');
echo "<p id = 'id_name'>$strings[array_rand($strings)]</p>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways:

**1. format-parsing functions** [documentation](https://www.php.net/printf)

```
printf("<p id = 'id_name'>%s</p>", $strings[array_rand($strings)]);
```

**2. concatenation:** [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo "<p id = 'id_name'>" . $strings[array_rand($strings)] . "</p>";
```

**3. curly braces:** [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

```
echo "<p id = 'id_name'>{$strings[array_rand($strings)]}</p>";
```

**4. intermediate "simple" variable:** [documentaion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

```
$randString = $strings[array_rand($strings)];
echo "<p id = 'id_name'>$randString</p>";
```

Comment: Derrr, I have updated to include what I think is actually the cleanest approach, `printf`!

Answer (score 1):

```
$strings = array('string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3');
echo '<p id="id_name">'.$strings[array_rand($strings)].'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put curly brackets around your variable:

```
$strings = array('string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3');
echo "<p id = 'id_name'>{$strings[array_rand($strings)]}</p>";
```

See the [example on codepad](http://codepad.org/kOj7TLE8).